# Google maps: Get click location in function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am allowing the user to create, edit and delete polygons in google maps. The user can decide to enter text for each polygon which *should* then appear in an info window when the polygon is clicked. The code below shows how this is possible. My problem is that I currently cannot detect the location of the click event - I need to know this since this is where the info window would be displayed. I have tried so many ways to get this work.

In the code below, tmfPolygonObjects[i][9] contains the text to be shown in the info window.

I somehow need to capture the event in the function, but cannot work this out. Any advice would be very welcome...

```
function tmfAddPolygonInfoWindowListener(myPolygon, i, myPolygonInfoWindow) { 
  tmfPolygon = myPolygon;
  tmfPolygonInfoWindow = myPolygonInfoWindow;
  tmfShowPolygonInfoWindowListener[i] = google.maps.event.addListener(tmfPolygon, 'click', (function(tmfPolygon, i) {
      return function() {
              tmfPolygonInfoWindow.setContent(tmfPolygonObjects[i][9]);

              // this is where I would set the position of the info window IF I could detect the event
              tmfPolygonInfoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng()); 
              tmfPolygonInfoWindow.open(map, tmfPolygon);
          }
      }
  })(tmfPolygon, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself. Simply needed 'event' to be added into return function(). Updated code is shown below.

```
function tmfAddPolygonInfoWindowListener(myPolygon, i, myPolygonInfoWindow) { 

tmfPolygon = myPolygon;
  tmfPolygonInfoWindow = myPolygonInfoWindow;
  tmfShowPolygonInfoWindowListener[i] = google.maps.event.addListener(tmfPolygon, 'click', (function(tmfPolygon, i) {
      return function(event) {
              tmfPolygonInfoWindow.setContent(tmfPolygonObjects[i][9]);

          // this is where I would set the position of the info window IF I could detect the event
          tmfPolygonInfoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng); 
          tmfPolygonInfoWindow.open(map, tmfPolygon);
      }
  }
  })(tmfPolygon, i));
}
```